# How to use interpolation to make the curve smooth?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, smoothing

I was plotting the weighing functions for some channels of a satellite where I need the fit to be smooth. I used the following code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
from turtle import color
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import example_data as ex

# reading the transmittance data
tau_level = np.squeeze(np.load('/home/swadhin/rttov/wrapper/tau_level.npy'))
print(np.max(tau_level))

# computing the difference of transmittance of different layers
ans = []
for i in range(len(tau_level)):
    l = []
    for j in range(len(tau_level[i])-1):
        a = tau_level[i][j]-tau_level[i][j+1]
        l.append(a)
    ans.append(l)
print(np.max(ans))

p = []
p_plt = []
s = ex.p_ex[0]  # importing the pressure profile from the data file
for x in range(len(s)-1):
    # taking the difference between the consecutive pressure levels on log scale
    y = np.abs(np.log(s[x]) - np.log(s[x+1]))
    # midpoint of two pressure levels as a representation of that layer for plotting
    p1 = (s[x]+s[x+1])/2
    p.append(y)
    p_plt.append(p1)
print(np.shape(p))

# weighting functions for different channels
plot = np.array([i / j for i, j in zip(ans, p)])


# Plotting the weighting functions for different channels
x_plt_store = []

for i in plot:
    x_plt = np.array(i/max(i))
    plt.plot(x_plt,p_plt)
    x_plt_store.append(x_plt)
x_plt_store = np.nan_to_num(x_plt_store)  #masking tthe nan or inf values
print(x_plt_store)
# interpolating for a smoother plot

x_new_store = []
y_spl = []
for i in x_plt_store:
    x_new = np.linspace(i.min(),i.max(),500) # 500 represents number of points to make between i.min and i.max
    x_new_store.append(x_new)
    spl = make_interp_spline(i, p_plt, k=3)
    y_spl.append(spl)

p_smooth = y_spl(x_new_store)
plt.plot(x_new_store, p_smooth)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1000, 100))
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1000])
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('/home/swadhin/rttov/wrapper/wfn_insat.png',
            format='png', dpi=1000)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/swadhin/rttov/wrapper/wfn.py in <cell line: 50>()

     51     x_new = np.linspace(i.min(),i.max(),500) # 500 represents number of points to make between i.min and i.max
     52     x_new_store.append(x_new)
---> 53     spl = make_interp_spline(i, p_plt, k=3)
     54     y_spl.append(spl)
     56 p_smooth = y_spl(x_new_store)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rttov/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py:1067, in make_interp_spline(x, y, k, t, bc_type, axis, check_finite)
   1065     raise ValueError("Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.")
   1066 if np.any(x[1:] == x[:-1]):
-> 1067     raise ValueError("Expect x to not have duplicates")
   1068 if k < 0:
   1069     raise ValueError("Expect non-negative k.")

ValueError: Expect x to not have duplicates
```

The plot I got before without smoothening is like this:
[image]

I am attaching the relevant files in case anyone wants to have a look.

tau_level = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MPUktkl2nG2DQ-pxPWDrbI7oxbAlJb-N/view?usp=sharing

p_ex = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MeMuJf5nTSCPItWTs5b9TzEgGs9gqpDe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the error is evident. Normally in a function the dependent variable is Y and X is the independent (Y depends on X) and thus you expect only one value of X. In your case you have several X values while only having one Y . Seems like your X depends on Y. So if you reverse your X and Y  arrays in your data it will work.

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte you are right, but for my application, I need the plot to be like this. Can I inverse the arrays, get the interpolated values and then again reverse them to plot like this?

Comment: Yes that would probably work perfectly